# How to calculate the median (without np.median) from frequency data?

Tags: arrays, numpy, data-analysis, median, exploratory-data-analysis

I am trying to create a function which receives an ordered array of values and associated frequencies as input and produces the median of the observations as output. My idea was to recreate the original data set by repeatedly adding each value, in order, to a new variable according to its frequency of occurrence. After that, I would just call a function I've already created for calculating the median of a set of raw observations.

So, for example. So we have:

```
severities = np.arange(7)
with_helmet = np.array([248, 58, 11, 3, 2, 8, 1])
```

Then I want my function to add zero 248 times, one 58 times, and so on. I'm new to numpy, and I'm embarrassed to say I'm not sure how to do this. A helpful function I found was

```
np.repeat(array, repeats)
```

but that duplicates each element a set number of times, whereas I want to duplicate each element in values the number of times it occurs (i.e. according to the corresponding frequency value).

Can anyone provide in suggestions (in base python and numpy only)?

Comment: What's wrong with using `np.repeat` ? `np.median(np.repeat(severities, with_helmet))` sounds reasonable to me to calculate the median (although it wont scale well for large frequencies).

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I keep missing tthe element-wise properties of numpy arrays! And again you're right about the scaling problem. This isn't a problem for my data sets, but I wonder how you would approach calculating the median (without np.median) without recreating the original data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, this is it:

```
import numpy as np
import collections

severities = np.arange(7)
with_helmet = np.array([248, 58, 11, 3, 2, 8, 1])

ans = np.repeat(severities, with_helmet)
counter = collections.Counter(ans)
print(ans)
print(counter)
```

Answer (score 2):

With regard to just calculating the median given frequencies:

```
import numpy as np

severities = np.arange(7)
with_helmet = np.array([248, 58, 11, 3, 2, 8, 1])

np.median(np.repeat(severities, with_helmet))
```

will work fine for simple cases.

Then you asked:

> You're right about the scaling problem. This isn't a problem for my
> data sets, but I wonder how you would approach calculating the median
> (without np.median) without recreating the original data set?

#### Here is a way that will scale better:

Explanation:

Given your data is basically a frequency table:

| Number | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 248 |
| 1 | 58 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 8 |
| 6 | 1 |

You can pin the median point (sum of frequency divided by two) to a number in the left column. `np.searchsorted` provides such functionality, but requires a monotinically increasing array as an input (of which the frequency column isn't). To make this possible I use `np.cumsum` over frequencies to get another representation of the frequences which can be used with `np.searchsorted`.

Assuming the number column is already sorted we can get a linear time and space algorithm respective the the length of the table:

```py
import numpy as np
import unittest
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike

def median_from_frequencies(numbers: ArrayLike, frequencies: ArrayLike):
    """
    Parameters:
    -----------
    numbers: ArrayLike, assumed sorted numbers
    frequencies: ArrayLike, frequencies of said numbers
    """
    bins = np.cumsum(frequencies)
    mid = bins[-1] / 2
    idx = np.searchsorted(bins, mid)
    result = numbers[idx]
    if mid.is_integer():
        result = (result + numbers[idx + 1]) / 2
    return result


class TestMedian(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_simple_length_1(self):
        a = np.array([0])
        numbers = np.array([0])
        frequencies = np.array([1])
        median1 = np.median(a)
        median2 = median_from_frequencies(numbers, frequencies)
        self.assertEqual(median1, median2)

    def test_simple_length_2(self):
        a = np.array([0,1])
        numbers = np.array([0,1])
        frequencies = np.array([1,1])
        median1 = np.median(a)
        median2 = median_from_frequencies(numbers, frequencies)
        self.assertEqual(median1, median2)

    def test_simple_length_4(self):
        a = np.array([1,1,2,2])
        numbers = np.array([1,2])
        frequencies = np.array([2,2])
        median1 = np.median(a)
        median2 = median_from_frequencies(numbers, frequencies)
        self.assertEqual(median1, median2)

    def test_length_5(self):
        a = np.array([10,10,20,30,30])
        numbers = np.array([10,20,30])
        frequencies = np.array([2,1,2])
        median1 = np.median(a)
        median2 = median_from_frequencies(numbers, frequencies)
        self.assertEqual(median1, median2)

    def test_length_7(self):
        a = np.array([1,1,2,2,7,7,7])
        numbers = np.array([1,2,7])
        frequencies = np.array([2,2,3])
        median1 = np.median(a)
        median2 = median_from_frequencies(numbers, frequencies)
        self.assertEqual(median1, median2)

    def test_your_numbers(self):
        severities = np.arange(7)
        with_helmet = np.array([248, 58, 11, 3, 2, 8, 1])

        a = np.repeat(severities, with_helmet)
        numbers = severities
        frequencies = with_helmet

        median1 = np.median(a)
        median2 = median_from_frequencies(numbers, frequencies)
        self.assertEqual(median1, median2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
......
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.002s

OK
```